# Stochastic Calculus for Jump Processes: Squared Compound Poisson Compensated Stochastic Integral

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, poisson-process

I'm reading [these notes on stochastic calculus for jump processes](https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/nprivault/MA5182/stochastic-calculus-jump-processes.pdf) which are great.

On page 670 of these notes, the author derives the expected value of the squared compound Poisson compensated stochastic integral.

Let $N_t$ be a Poisson process with intensity $\lambda$ and $Z$ a sequence of square-integrable random variables.

The process $Y_t$ is then given by the random sum $Y_t := Z_1 + Z_2 + \ldots + Z_{N_t} = \sum_{k=1}^{N_t} Z_k$.

In my understanding the Poisson process $N_t$ gives the jump times and the $Z_{N_t}$ is a random variable modelling how much we jump when $N_t=1$.

Let $\phi_{t}$ be a stochastic process adapted to the filtration generated by $Y_t$ admitting left limits $\phi_{t-} := \lim_{s \rightarrow t} \phi_s$.

My question concerns this expectation of the squared integral:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left[ \left (\int_0^T \phi_{t-} \ (dY_t - \lambda \mathbb{E}[Z] dt) \right)^2 \right] = \lambda \mathbb{E}[|Z|^2] \mathbb{E} \left[ \int_0^T | \phi_{t-} |^2 \right]
\end{align}
$$

The author proves it by first separating the squared integral into

$$
\begin{align}
&\left(\int_0^T \phi_{t-} \ (dY_t - \lambda \mathbb{E}[Z] dt) \right)^2 \\
&= 2 \int_0^T \phi_{t-} \int_0^{t-} \phi_{s-} (dY_s - \lambda \mathbb{E}[Z] ds) (dY_t - \lambda \mathbb{E}[Z] dt) \\
& \quad + \int_0^T |\phi_{t-}|^2 |Z_{N_t}|^2 dN_t \quad \leftarrow \text{how did this arrive here?}
\end{align}
$$

where I have no clue where the last line came from.

I do see that use of the stochastic Fubini-type theorem while integrating over time.

Here is a screenshot of the authors notes while deriving the [proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJc6h.png).

Any help or pointing me into a useful direction is greatly appreciated!

PS: I'm not a mathematician by training so apologies if I butchered the definitions. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After going on a literature hunt I found an answer in this script on [page 30](https://wt.iam.uni-bonn.de/fileadmin/WT/Inhalt/people/Andreas_Eberle/StoAn1213/StochasticAnalysisNotes1213.pdf).

The integral is decomposed into its off-diagonal terms (first row) and its diagonal/quadratic terms (second row).

The scaling factor of 2 occurs since we're integrating twice over the same domain.

Now to the quadratic term:

We are working with a compensated Poisson process which means that the process is centered around zero.

$$
\mathbb{E}[Y_t] = \lambda \mathbb{E}[Z] t
$$

Discretizing the integral gives us:
$$
\sum (\Delta \phi_{t-})^2 \Delta[Y_t - \lambda \mathbb{E}[Z]]\ \Delta[Y_t - \lambda \mathbb{E}[Z]]
$$

Substituting in the mean $\mathbb{E}[Y_t] = \mathbb{E}[Y_t]$ yields:
$$
\sum_t (\Delta \phi_{t-})^2 \Delta[Y_t - \mathbb{E}[Y_t]]^2
$$
where $ \Delta[Y_t - \mathbb{E}[Y_t]]^2$ is the diagonal term of the covariance for an infinitessimal small timestep $\Delta$.

We further know that the variance for a Poisson process $N_t$ of length $t$ is

$$
\mathbb{V}[N_t] = \lambda t
$$

and that the variance of a scaled random variable $X$ is
$$
\mathbb{V}[aX] = a^2 \mathbb{V}[X].
$$

Since the jumps of the compensated Poisson process are modulated of sorts by the random variable $Z$ we obtain:

$$
\sum_t (\Delta \phi_{t-})^2 \Delta[Y_t - \mathbb{E}[Y_t]]^2 \\
= \sum_t (\Delta \phi_{t-})^2 \mathbb{V}[Z \Delta N_t] \\
= \sum_t (\Delta \phi_{t-})^2 Z^2 \mathbb{V}[\Delta N_t] \\
= \sum_t (\Delta \phi_{t-})^2 Z^2 \lambda \Delta t
$$

the continuous version of which is

$$
\int \phi_{t-}^2 Z^2 \lambda dt
$$